# ngSwitch inside ngRepeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to display

Disc 1

track[1]

track[n]

Disc 2

track[1]

track[n]

Where do I need to add those headings?

```
<h3>Track List:</h3>
<div ng-repeat="track in tracks">
  <div ng-switch on="track.disc_number">
    <div ng-switch-when="1" >
      <div>
        <div id="track">
          {{track.track_number}}) {{track.name}}
          <span>({{track.duration_ms | date : 'mm:ss'}})</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2" >
        <div id="track">
          {{track.track_number}}) {{track.name}}
          <span>({{track.duration_ms | date : 'mm:ss'}})</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a switch here.
Try reading the docs for `ng-repeat`'s builtin `filter`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<h3>Track List:</h3>
<div ng-repeat="disc in [1, 2]">
    <h4>Disc {{disc}}</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="track in tracks | filter: {disc_number: disc}">
        <div id="track">
            {{track.track_number}}) {{track.name}}
            <span>({{track.duration_ms | date : 'mm:ss'}})</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jlycypdkSkrKj8HfcEAw?p=preview